# 'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 22 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true

Tags: flutter

```
class CustomCircleAvatar extends StatefulWidget {
final Image myImage;

final String initials;

CustomCircleAvatar({this.myImage, this.initials});

@override
_CustomCircleAvatarState createState() => new _CustomCircleAvatarState();
}

class _CustomCircleAvatarState extends State {
bool _checkLoading = true;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
widget.myImage.image.resolve(new ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool synchronousCall) {
if (mounted) {
setState(() {
_checkLoading = false;
});
}
}));
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return _checkLoading == true
? new CircleAvatar(
child: new Text(
widget.initials,
style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60),
))
: new CircleAvatar(
backgroundImage: widget.myImage.image,
);
}
}

Positioned _profilePhoto(BuildContext context) {
return Positioned(
bottom: -70,
child: Container(
width: 150.0,
height: 150.0,
padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, shape: BoxShape.circle),
child: CustomCircleAvatar(
myImage: Image.network(sellerPicture), // This sellerPicture i got from sharedPreferences
initials: '$sellerName'.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(),
),
),
);
}
```

help me, the image Show from URL but the terminal say that URL != null is not true
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building ProfileScreen(dirty, state: _ProfileScreenState#29296):
'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 22 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true.

Comment: Have you get image url from sharedPreferences?

Comment: `  _loadSellerPictureUrl() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      sellerPicture = (prefs.getString('sellerPicture') ?? '');
      return sellerPicture;
    });
  }`

Comment: Could you update your current question including [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be incomplete. If the error appears once but the image from the URL is still displayed on the widget, it's likely that the Widget tries to load the image from `url` that hasn't been initialized. Possibly during first render of the screen, url is still empty, and on reload (i.e. via `setState()`), the url has been initialized. A workaround for this issue is to set a default image url in the parameter.

Or add a checker for `sellerPicture`

```dart
Container(
  /// Check if sellerPicture is null
  child: sellerPicture != null ? 
      CustomCircleAvatar(
      myImage: Image.network(sellerPicture), // This sellerPicture i got from 
      sharedPreferences
      initials: '$sellerName'.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(),
    ),
    /// if sellerPicture is null, display a default image Widget
    /// i.e. image from local Assets
    : DefaultImageWidget(),
  ),
)
```